# Lie derivative of metric $g$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\varphi_t$ be a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated by a vector field $V$ on $M$, and the metric is given by 
$$
g_{ij}(x,t)=\varphi_t^*g_{ij}(x,0)
$$

How to show that $\partial_tg=\mathcal{L}_Vg$ ? $\mathcal{L}_Vg$ is Lie derivative of $g$.

Besides, 1,Why a vector field can generate a one-parameter group?

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$2,How to express the $\varphi_t^*g_{ij}(x,0)$ under the local coordinate?

Comment: According to the approach I'm familiar with, this is exactly the definition of the Lie derivative of the metric. What's your definition?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval   Maybe ,I confuse it with differential forms. What's your definition ?